Convert RGB(A) GeoPDF to Grayscale GeoTIFF with GDAL
I'm using the GDAL command line tools gdal_warp and gdal_translate to convert RGB(A) GeoPDF images into GeoTIFF images. Unfortunately I found no config option that changes the RGB(A) color space to Grayscale.
I know it's possible to convert colors with gdal_calc.py (How to convert 4band RGB/A GeoTiff to 1band Gray GeoTiif?), but I would prefer a single step conversion.
With GDAL VRT we could use Python Pixel Functions to change our raster pixels, but I couldn't find any specific example. Is there anyone in this forum who has experience here? ...@EvenRouault?

What formula do you want to apply for the conversion from RGB into single band?

To be honest... I have no idea, Raster editing is a completely new territory for me. I have seen that Python Pillow uses "Floyd-Steinberg" dithering, but I have no special preferences.

There are some suggestions in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71472/how-to-convert-4-channel-png-files-to-grayscale-geotiffs. Transform into grayscale is not a common need in GIS. Writing a new pixel function for VRT feels like a good solution, but it feels also complicated. I think I would use some photo editor like GIMP myself.

The rgb2pct tool, as documented https://gdal.org/programs/rgb2pct.html, does not make a grayscale image. It makes a single band paletted image. User can delete the color palette but the result would not be what is desired.

Wanted to know what AI is telling me and asked MS Copilot (aka ChatGPT), and the answer looked promising:
How to convert RGB(A) GeoPDF to Grayscale GeoTIFF with GDAL


The AI gives a lunatic and useless answer. It gives false information about what GDAL does by default, and it asks user to do odd things.

@user30184 you are right. At first glance it looked quite good, but on closer inspection it turned out to be a piece of junk

"it turned out to be a piece of junk" - then why haven't you deleted it? Just wasted 5 minutes I'll never get back.

@JeshuaLacock If you have a problem with losing 5 minutes of your precious time, then maybe you shouldn't be dealing with IT.

You're missing the point - why leave a post that is riddled with misinformation? Its not helping anyone, just wasting peoples time.
